# Ansible: lineinfile module using regexp and backrefs

Tags: ansible

I am trying to ensure that a line ends with 'audit=1"'. The before state is:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=vg00/lv_root rhgb
>   quiet"

The after state should be:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=vg00/lv_root rhgb quiet
>   audit=1"

Working with the Ansible lineinfile module I can add that statement if its missing, but repeated runs keep appending 'audit=1"' even if it's present. I have been playing with the regexp and negative look-ahead assertions, and just cannot get the syntax correct.

Here is example play I have:

```
  - name: grub - adjust
    lineinfile:
      path: /home/vwadmin/grub-test
      regexp: '(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=.*)"(?!audit=1")'
      line: '\1 audit=1"'
      backrefs: yes
      state: present
```

Edit: Using Pacifist's suggestion I have a working solution. Confirmed to add my audit=1 statement if missing, and do nothing if present.

```
  - name: grub - check
    shell: grep -c 'audit' /etc/default/grub
    register: grub_file
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: grub - adjust
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/default/grub
      regexp: '(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=.*)"'
      line: '\1 audit=1"'
      backrefs: yes
      state: present
    when: grub_file.stdout == "0"
```

Note: I can't help but feel the reason I couldn't get it working without a pre-step, and why it doesn't work properly with check_mode, is that the negative look-ahead is not defined correctly for this case. From what I understand, the regexp match should fail when the negative look-ahead succeeds, which should cause the module to not take action. Looking at another example of this on [GG](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ansible-project/JvHfchsgRaU/Vw_CzBbvadgJ) I am wondering if root issue is the greedy nature of the .* wildcard in the first group match. /shrug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) is doing its work that is adding whatever is given in `line` and line is identified by your `regexp`. So no matter what value your setting already has, it will be overridden by your new `line`.

There are two approaches that you can use :

1. Using `check_mode` with `failed_when`.
2. Using `shell` module to `grep` the content beforehand.

**Check_Mode** (I can not get this working though but it has been recommended everywhere else):

```
- name: grub - adjust
  lineinfile: 
      name: /home/vwadmin/grub-test
      regexp: '(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=.*)'
      line: '\1 audit=1"'
      backrefs: yes
      state: present
   check_mode: yes
   register: presence
   failed_when: presence.changed
```

**Using grep** (This one is working fine for me)

```
- name: grub - adjust
  shell: grep -c 'audit' /home/vwadmin/grub-test 
  register: file
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Present
  debug: msg="audit is present"
  when: file.stdout != "0"

- name: Not Present
  debug: msg="audit is not present"
  when: file.stdout == "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to do something similar with `console` kernel options and ended up with this:

```
- name: "Ensure console kernel options are set"
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/default/grub
    regexp: ^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"(?P<defaults>.*?)\s*(?P<console> console=.*)?\"$
    line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="\g<defaults> {{ kernel_console }}"
    backrefs: yes
  register: grub_changed

- name: "Rebuild grub"
  command: grub2-mkconfig –o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg >/dev/null
  when:
    - grub_changed.changed
```

the key part of the regexp is `(?P<defaults>.*?)`: the last question mark - which makes the match less greedy, allows the optional  `console=.*` to be picked up without continually appending another `console` to the end of the line in the `line` as it did with your `audit`. main issue is that it assumes that its always the last (set of) options in the line and i always end up with a white space if there is no `console` defined. but it works!